# kinect and raspberry

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i want to connect kinect with raspberry pi3. i install ros indigo and freenect_launch package.
when i launch freenect, i receive all topic but with a message "searching device"
i make the same configuration with laptop, it works well.
Can you help me please to solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236516/kinect-and-raspberry/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) on 2016-06-10**:
can you just post the link of the tutorial you followed to install ROS on the RaspberryPi? So we can look up which packages of ROS are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to verify that you have the necessary kernel drivers and udev rules installed on the RaspberryPi3.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-06-09**:
how? can you explain it more please?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please be more precise! Which version of the kinect you are using? Kinect v1 (Xbox 360) oder Kinect v2 (Xbox One)? Kinect v2 works only with USB 3.0. The Raspberry Pi 3 has only USB2.0 ports. Keep that in mind when using this configuration.

---

Originally posted by [easyspidy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26933/easyspidy/) with karma: 46 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1